# Linear transformation $T:R^{3}\to R^{3}$ with a given eigenvecor $v_{1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to find a linear transformation like in the title such that $R^{3}$ is the sum of its two cyclic subspaces.

The eigenvector I'm given is $v_{1}=[1,1,0]$.
The transformation I found with that eigenvector is given by the next matrix,

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

The cyclic subspace part is the one I can't figure out.
How can I write $R^{3}$ as that sum?

Comment: Since you are looking for only two cyclic subspaces, one of them has to be two dimensional. An eigenvector generates a one-dimensional cyclic space, but a [generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) can generate higher dimensional cyclic spaces. However, only non-diagonalizable matrices have generalized eigenvectors, and yours is diagonalizable. You are right in having only two eigenvalues, but you need a non-diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: I believe you put me right on track. Thank you so much for your insight.

Comment: That's good - I was actually feeling a little fuzzy when I posted that and wasn't certain afterwards if my deduction that your matrix was diagonalizable was accurate. But if you've figured out what to do, that is all that matters.